# How do you query a one-to-many relationship in an SQLAlchemy object instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have the following (in Python 3 and SQLAlchemy):

```
class Book(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chapters = relationship("Chapter", backref="book")

class Chapter(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Book.id))

def check_for_chapter(book): 
    # This is where I want to check to see if the book has a specific chapter.
    for chapter in book.chapters:
        if chapter.name == "57th Arabian Tale"
            return chapter
    return None
```

This feels like a 'non-idiomatic' approach, because it seems unlikely to leverage the database to search for the given chapter. In the worst case, it seems like `n` calls to the db will be made to check for chapter titles, though my limited understanding of SQLAlchemy suggests this can be configured around. What I don't know is if there is a way to initiate a query directly against only the relation of an object you've already fetched? If so, how does one do that?

Comment: Why not query the `Chapter` table for `book.id`? That will only take one query

Comment: Note that this is a simplified case: it may very well be that initiating a second, independent query is the quickest/best way at this information. But a) The original object was checked for various security concerns and b) It may already have that information in-cache, and I'm not sure if a separate query would by necessity bypass any caching of the original object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to get a specific chapter of a specific book, the code below should do it in one SQL statement:

```
book = ...  # get book instance 

chapter = (
    session.query(Chapter)
    .with_parent(book)
    .filter(Chapter.name == "57th Arabian Tale")
    .one()
)
```

If, for example, you have only book title and chapter title, you could do this:

```
chapter = (
    session.query(Chapter)
    .join(Book)
    .filter(Book.name == "One Thousand and One Nights")
    .filter(Chapter.name == "57th Arabian Tale")
    .one()
)
```

*Also read [Querying with Joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins) and the rest of [SQLAlchemy Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/index.html).*